# I want to know the IP adress of machine in network. Why do I get 127.0.0.1?

Tags: java

Why i am gettng  IP Addres as 127.0.0.1

This is my sample program for what i am using for  getting the IP Address

```
package com;

import java.net.InetAddress;    
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Test {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String ips = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress().trim();
        System.out.println(ips);
    }

}
```

Comment: because 127.0.0.1 is `localhost`?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765578/get-local-ip-address-without-connecting-to-the-internet), it uses interface enumeration to find an interface which isn't the loopback one.

Comment: The IP address 127.0.0.1 is a special purpose address reserved for use on each computer. 127.0.0.1 is conventionally a computer's loopback address. Network software and utilities can use 127.0.0.1 to access a local computer's TCP/IP network resources. Messages sent to loopback IP addresses like 127.0.0.1 don't reach outside the local area network (LAN) but instead are automatically re-routed by the computer's own network adapter back to the receiving end of the TCP/IP stack. More over, [see](http://superuser.com/q/31824).

Answer (score 7):

That is the IP address from your local server (= localhost). It is used when you are accessing the computer the program is running on..

Comment: thanks for the answers , my question is why i am not getting the IP ??

Comment: @Preethi kindly edit the question. it read why im getting IP address

Answer (score 3):

```
Enumeration e=NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

while(e.hasMoreElements())
{
    NetworkInterface n=(NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
    Enumeration ee = n.getInetAddresses();
    while(ee.hasMoreElements())
    {
        InetAddress i= (InetAddress) ee.nextElement();
        System.out.println(i.getHostAddress());
    }
}
```

You can use above code to get ip addresses of your machine.

See [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/how-to-get-ip-address-of-our-own-system-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Your localhost is `127.0.0.1`. See the [InetAddress#getLocalHost()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29)

> Returns the address of the local host. This is achieved by retrieving the name of the host from the system, then resolving that name into an InetAddress.

A localhost is, put plainly, the standard hostname given to the address assigned to the loopback network interface. Translated into an IP address, a localhost is always designated as 127.0.0.1.

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost):

> In computer networking, localhost means this computer. It is a hostname that the computer's software and users may employ to access the computer's own network services via its loopback network interface. On most computer systems, localhost resolves to the address **127.0.0.1**, which is the most-commonly used IPv4 loopback address, and to the IPv6 loopback address **::1.**

Comment: Note that while the "hostname `localhost`" resolves to 127.0.0.1, the hostname of the local host may resolve to another address. They are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

You get 127.0.0.1 on your system because that's what the *machine's name* resolves to. **On other systems you may get a different address.**

For example, I get `127.0.1.1` because my machine is called `koivu` and I have this line in my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1   koivu
```

If I had some other IP address I would get that address instead.

Answer (score 1):

This one give ip instead of localhost address

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GetIPAddress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InetAddress thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("IP:" + thisIp.getHostAddress());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example this is returning my LAN IP address: `System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());`

You have multiple IP addresses probably and that is causing your troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are accessing your application from your `localhost`