# How to execute a java proram on a Linux machine without a script?

Tags: java, unix

We are using Ubuntu machienes as our servers, such we got 14 servers.

The command ifconfig works on all terminals it gives specific IP address.

When I ran the following java program through a script, on one of the 14 servers I get the host ip as standard 127.0.0.1 (I uploaded this file and script on only 2 machines as of now)

```
package com;

import java.net.Inet4Address;

public class IpAddressTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String ipaddress = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        String hostname = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        System.out.println("THE  IP ADDRESS IS" + ipaddress);
        System.out.println("THE  HOST NAME IS" + hostname);

    }
}
```

To test this program as which server will give me IP as 127.0.0.1, I need to upload this java class file and related script to execute that on all of the 14 servers.

Is there any other alternate way of finding that? I want to check if i can get the IP THROUGH java , but for this i need to upload these java file and script file to all 14 servers .so asking is there any alternate way

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? get the IP address of all 14 servers? why not a simple shell script?

Comment: @Protostome yes correct i want to check if i can get the IP THROUGH java , but for this i need to upload these java file and script file  to all 14 servers .so asking is there any alternate way

Comment: You do know that `127.0.0.1` is a loopback localhost address? All the machines would give you that address. I think you're looking to find the LAN IP but I guess your program isn't doing that.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to use Java, then you have to upload the classes and the script to every server.To find all the IP addresses: [Get local IP-Address without connecting to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765578/get-local-ip-address-without-connecting-to-the-internet)