# Why getHostAddress() output differs when run in different environment?

Tags: java, operating-system, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java InetAddress.getLocalHost(); returns 127.0.0.1 … how to get REAL IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381316/java-inetaddress-getlocalhost-returns-127-0-0-1-how-to-get-real-ip)

I have run the below code in different operation system. When i run this in ubuntu 11.4 I got 127.0.1.1 but the same time i got actual ip 192.XXX.XXX.XXX in windows.
How can i get actual ip?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GetIPAddress {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
   try {
        InetAddress thisIp =InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("IP:"+thisIp.getHostAddress());
       }
      catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Cheers..

Comment: You'll have to query an IP on a specific device. It just so happens that the `localhost` address resolves to `127..` on one OS and `192..` on other. What was the OS that gave you `192..`?

Comment: One host can have many different IP addresses at the same time, there is no single one that is the "actual IP", they're all valid for different purposes.

Comment: @iccthedral I got actual ip in windows environment.