# Why InetAddress.getLocalHost() behaving differently in Java 1.7?

Tags: java, networking, java-7

```
String hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

The above code works differently on Java 1.7 and 1.6. In 1.6, it returns correct IP allocated to the system (10.4...). In 1.7, it returns 127.0.0.1.

To workaround this issue, I have to use `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` and get `InetAddress` from it. I will try to connect to every `InetAddress` available until once succeeds. This works well but I am wondering why Java 1.7 is behaving differently?

Any help would be great.

Comment: on my ubuntu box, with openjdk 1.6.0_27, oracle java 1.6.0_33, and openjdk 1.7.0_15 this returns 127.0.1.1

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly, but a few ideas:

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29):

> Returns the address of the local host. **This is achieved by retrieving the name of the host from the system**, then resolving that name into an InetAddress.

Would indicate that the change to `gethostname` mentioned by @Jayamohan *would* be relevant.

---

Also from the docs

> If the operation is not allowed, an InetAddress representing the loopback address is returned.

Which is what you're getting.

---

127.0.0.1 is indeed a valid address for your machine (most likely).  In a multi-address system, how is the JVM to determine which IP *you* want?

[More reading, similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381316/java-inetaddress-getlocalhost-returns-127-0-0-1-how-to-get-real-ip)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the change since `JDK 7u4`.

The details are available [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7166687)

> This is not really a bug but is a behavior change in 7u4. Prior to 7u4
> the Linux implementation used gethostname, with 7u4 it uses
> getnameinfo. This change was an error that crept in with the Mac port.

Comment: That bug report talks about host name not host address. I have issues with host address. Thanks for the help.