# How do I check if the broadcast packet was sent from this machine?

Tags: java, networking, udp

I am writing a game in Java using `libGDX`. I want to add local area network discovery into the game, so players will only have to press a button to start a multiplayer game. To achieve this, each client broadcasts `UDP` packets to a certain port (`255.255.255.255:40667`) and listens for other incoming packets on this port to create a list of other players on the network.

This works perfectly, but the packets which were broadcasted by a machine are also received by it.

For example:
If there are 2 machines on the network with the program running

> Machine 1 (192.168.1.137)
>
> Machine 2 (192.168.1.111)

Then the 1st machine receives packets from `192.168.1.111` AND from `192.168.1.137` 
I am trying to find a way to determine if the packet came from my own address, but I can't figure it out.

`InetAddress.getLocalHost()` returns `127.0.1.1`, and reading the local address from the outbound socket returns `0.0 0.0`
How do I determine if the packet was sent from the same machine?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java InetAddress.getLocalHost(); returns 127.0.0.1 ... how to get REAL IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381316/java-inetaddress-getlocalhost-returns-127-0-0-1-how-to-get-real-ip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your machine usually has multiple IP addresses and calling to localhost often returns `127.0.1.1`
There is several options how to determine local IP address, one is just to create socket connection:

```
// Here is the existing IP address in my local network, or you will get the exception
try (Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.1", 80)) {
    System.out.println(socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress());
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can manually assosiate your host name with address modifying:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Add `10.10.10.1 test` for example and in your app just call:

```
System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("test").getHostAddress());
```

command `hostname` in cmd will return you the hostname.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, this is a TCP socket you mean, I am going to try that now