# Sending UDP from Java to Python not working

Tags: java, python, sockets, udp, localhost

### Goal

I am trying to send data over UDP from a Java server to a Python client on the same machine.

### Environment

- **Device/OS:** Jetson nano with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
- **JavaC version:** javac 11.0.4
- **Java version:**

  - openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
  - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
  - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode)

### Problem

I can send data from a Python test server, see code below, to the Python test client just fine. However, If I try to send data from the Java test server to the Python test client, nothing seems to arrive. The Java server doesn't throw an exception.

### Test client in Python (*working*)

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "localhost"
UDP_PORT = 9999

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

print("listening...")

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print("received message from: ", addr)
    print("payload: ", data)
```

### Test server in Python (*working*)

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto("Hello World", ("localhost", 9999))
```

### Test server in Java (*not working or doesn't reach the python client*)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TestSender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            byte[]         data    = "Hello world".getBytes();
            int            port    = 9999;
            InetAddress    address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            DatagramPacket packet  = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
            DatagramSocket socket  = new DatagramSocket();

            socket.send(packet);
            System.out.println("Data sent");

            socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may try to change `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` to `InetAddress.getByName("localhost")`. Probably, *getLocalHost* is returning your network device address, not the loopback address (127.0.0.1).

Comment: Seconding the above, the address returned may depend on your system, you can print it out to check it . See this for more information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381316/java-inetaddress-getlocalhost-returns-127-0-0-1-how-to-get-real-ip

Comment: Don't bind to localhost. Bind to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

returns the address of one of the interfaces of the machine.

### Solution

As @Gomiero suggested, using either

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
// or
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
```

solves the problem because in this case the client bound to `127.0.0.1` and does not accept packets from any other IP address.

### Note

As @user207421 suggested in most cases the proper solution to the problem would be to bind the client to `0.0.0.0` like this:

```
UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = 9999
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Binding the client to `0.0.0.0` resolves the issue with using `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` on the server-side because it makes the client accept data to any of its IP addresses.

However, I finally decided to bind the client to `127.0.0.1` now with the proper understanding of what that does, because I only want data from the local machine.

Comment: I didn't suggest any such thing, and this isn't necessary if you bind to 0.0.0.0, which is what I did suggest, and which is normal practice.

Comment: @user207421 You are right, sorry, that was not your suggestion I am changing that. However, `address = InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0");` does not seem to work. It results in `java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Datagram send failed`.

Comment: I didn't say that either. I said to *bind* to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost. The only bind to localhost here is in the Python code. All this other Java stuff is quite misguided. You should be able to send to a host via any of its reachable IP addresses if you don't prevent it via the bind as you are doing.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks, now I understand, I originally did not realise that I should change something on the client-side. That is exactly the answer I was looking for because I  was really confused that the original example with `InetAddress.getLocalHost();` did not work. However, binding the client to `127.0.0.1` is exactly what I need since I don't want data from another machine in the network in this case. I just didn't think about the exact mechanics well enough...